# Grid Search and High Variance

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameter, search

I am currently trying to optimise some parameters on my model (15000 samples). What I am finding is a relatively large variance in the loss function 2%-10% which makes it hard to identify which parameter is the best. This appears to happen based on how the random number generator splits the data into train/test sets.

I have tried :

- CV 5-fold
- Split of 75%

Fixing the random seed does help (or using the same test set), but it concerns me that I get such variations based on what samples are in the test set. It seems alarming that the 'best parameter' is so dependent on a particular shuffle of the data and I worry how it translates to real world use.

What are people's approach to situations like this? I was thinking I could just repeat each test multiple times and take the average, but that has very large computation costs and seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned it can be a good idea to repeat CV a few times and average the results to obtain a more reliable estimate

If you find many parameter constellations that are within one standard deviation (or in that neighborhood) of the best performing model, it can make sense to choose a model with a slightly worse CV performance, but with a simpler decision boundary (e.g. shallower decision trees, smaller gammas in an RBF-kernel SVM, stronger regularization parameters etc.) - something that was suggested for example [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1032181158).

Comment: That is a very interesting approach to the problem. Has opened my mind!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to repeat the K-fold CV a few times (with different seeds each time) and average the results. I'd guess that the high variance comes from the small size of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

- Averaging might help. You can optimize your hyper parameter tuning
  time using [Bayesian Hyper-parameter tuning](http://fastml.com/optimizing-hyperparams-with-hyperopt/) approach.
- Try to reduce the number of features or try algorithms like Random
  Forest with other standard techniques like k-fold repeated CV.
- Try creating new features which might help you differentiate classes